# How to remove "flash" button in CKEditor 3.x

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 3 on my web site, but I don't want show the "add flash" button in the editor. So I followed this advice:

http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Howto/Plugin_Removal

Now my `config.js` file looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
{
    config.linkShowAdvancedTab = false;
    config.linkShowTargetTab = false;
    config.removePlugins = 'flash';
};
```

However, the "add flash" button is still shown in the editor.
Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: Dang it, I must have read your question completely wrong when answering, must be a monday brainfart! I deleted my answer, sorry!

Comment: @Nenotlep: Too bad, I was happy already thinking about it as a solution to my problem :)